# How to access elements with getElementsByClassName within the <head>

Tags: javascript, html

A friend and i ran into an issue within the js plugin ( https://github.com/geibi/pictureserve ) we’ve built - relating the loading DOM, its img elements and the getElementsByClassName function. A simplified example:

Within the  we call document.getElementsByClassName with the class .pserve:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" dir="ltr">
    <head>
            <script>
            elements = document.getElementsByClassName("pserve");
            console.log(elements);
        </script>
```

Inside the HTML body we have four img elements in the present example:

```
<img class="pserve" /> 
<img class="pserve" />
<img class="pserve" />
<img class="pserve" />
```

The console is returning the following:

```
[item: function]
  0: img.pserve 
  1: img.pserve
  2: img.pserve
  3: img.pserve
```

But if you try to get the length of the elements array you get zero as result:

```
<head>
        <script>
            elements = document.getElementsByClassName("pserve");
            console.log(elements.length);
        </script>



==> returning value for the console.log is 0  ==> wrong
```

If you place the console call right before the `</body>` then you get the right returning value 4.

```
        <script>
            elements = document.getElementsByClassName("pserve");
            console.log(elements.length);
        </script>
 </body>



==> returning value for the console.log is 4  ==> right
```

So the questions are:

1. Is it possible and if so how to access the “elements” within the  via getElementsByClassName or is there another js function necessary or even better suitable.
2. The returning output with [item:function] with the four entries looks odd. Is there maybe another way to access those elements? e.g. via a function call or a call back?

Cheers r.

Comment: you have to have this in a dom-ready state - so add a handler to the window's load event.

Comment: With jQuery you could use the document ready function

Comment: One thing confuses me. How is it that you've written as much JavaScript as you have so far in that plugin, but you don't know one of the must fundamental aspects to working in the DOM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript is evaluated by the browser as it's encountered while parsing the HTML. In the `<head>`, the body of the document hasn't been seen yet.

Put your scripts at the end, or else put the code in a "load" or "ready" event handler.

Comment: hmmmm the linked plugin is a vanilla responsive image solution. If we put the scripts at the end there is the problem that the basic fallback images are loaded before the ones if need for the present viewport - images are loaded twice more or less. And the reason why we asked if there is another solution is, that there is already something known before the body is loaded, since 4 objects are already recognized but not accessible by getElementsByClassName as i described.

Comment: @rpk - it's very simple: JavaScript that runs in the `<head>` without waiting for the rest of the document to be parsed **cannot** access the rest of the document.  The DOM simply has not been built at that point.

Comment: @pointy - True. But it confuses me, why is the list of img objects been visible and known via the console.log pasted in the <head> (like shown in the first snippet). I guess the DOM hasn't been to be built for the image object exchange. So is there a chance to access those objects at this point already?

Comment: @rpk: It isn't known before the body is loaded. What happens is that `.getElementsByClassName` returns a "live list" of elements, which is empty. But by the time you make it to the console to view the output, the document has loaded, and the live list shows the current state of the DOM with respect to the class you provided.

Comment: ...even with collections that are not "live", some consoles can fool you because they don't make a copy of the list to represent a snapshot in time when the `console.log()` was invoked, but rather simply hold a reference and display its content when the developer finally expands the list in the console.

Answer (score 1):

**In your case `script` is executing before the DOM gets loaded with the respective elements.**

Put script just after all your content, like this

```
    <head>....</head>
    <body>

       // Content here...


     <script>
          elements = document.getElementsByClassName("pserve");
          console.log(elements.length);
     </script>

     </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window.load event. When you call script first time, browser dont know anything about this elements.

Comment: The browser already knows something like shown above otherwise it wouldn't show: [item: function]
  0: img.pserve 
  1: img.pserve
  2: img.pserve
  3: img.pserve   it seems only impossible to access them properly with getElementsByClassName